# PHP filter_input() function not working with CI controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, filter-input, input-filtering

PHPs `filter_input()` function is not working within CI controller. However it works inside a view.
The controller code is below.

```
class member extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $obj =& get_instance();
        $obj->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->load->library('pagination');     

    }

    public function editMember() {
        $mem_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        echo $mem_id;
    }
}
```

The url used to call the `editMember` function is like the one below.

```
https://mypage.com/member/editMember?id=mem001
```

The echo statement displays nothing.

When I try to get the input parameter using `$_GET['id']`, it works and echo statement shows `mem001` as in the example link above. If I use CodeIgniter's input class as below, it works.

```
$mem_id = $this->input->get('id');
echo $mem_id;
```

Could you please help on what is going wrong and how to fix this?
Thanks.

Here is `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` result.

```
string(9) "id=mem001"
```

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to achieve with the `filter_input` filter? you are filtering an `id` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL`, I'm confused since it's an `id`, not an email address

Comment: Well, `echo false` prints nothing. As @HastaDhana pointed out, you're checking an alphanumeric ID against an email validator, so the filter fails.

Comment: It's a cut and paste error. Its SANITIZE_STRING and not e-mail. Sorry about that.

Comment: Forgot to mention that even with SANITIZE_STRING, it is still not working. This is only inside the CI controller class. It works in views or in a standalone PHP form. I use PHP 5.6.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` and post its result?

Comment: Yes, provided in the post, @Jeto.

Comment: Does `$mem_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : false;` work?

Comment: Of course, `filter_var()` works

Answer (score 0):

```
public function editMember() {
if (isset($_GET["id"])) { 
if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) { 
    $mem_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    echo $mem_id;
} else { 
    $mem_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    echo $mem_id; 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: But you directly get the Id so why this type of code 

you can use direct $_GET('id');

Comment: Instead of using $_GET and then sanitizing the input with htmlspecialchars and other such filters, trying to use filter_input to make it more simple.